# Python's .strip() doesnt save outside of if statement?

Tags: python, scrapy, stocks

I have scrapy pulling data from a web page. An issue Ive run across is it pulls alot of whitespace and Ive elected to use .strip() as suggested by others. Ive run into an issue though

```
if a.strip():
    print a
if b.strip():
    print b
```

Returns:

```
a1
b1
.
.
.
```

But this:

```
if a.strip():
    aList.append(a)
if b.strip():
    bList.append(b)
print aList, bList
```

Returns this:

```
a1



    b1
```

Im trying to simulate the whitespace that I remove with .strip() here, but you get the point. For whatever reason it adds the whitespace to the list even though I told it not to. I can even print the list in the if statement and it also shows correctly, but for whatever reason, when I decide to print outside the if statements it doesnt work as I intended.

Here is my entire code:

```
# coding: utf-8
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter
import re
import csv
import urlparse
from stockscrape.items import EPSItem
from itertools import izip

class epsScrape(BaseSpider):
        name = "eps"
        allowed_domains = ["investors.com"]
        ifile = open('test.txt', "r")
        reader = csv.reader(ifile)
        start_urls = []
        for row in ifile:
                url = row.replace("\n","")
                if url == "symbol":
                        continue
                else:
                        start_urls.append("http://research.investors.com/quotes/nyse-" + url + ".htm")
        ifile.close()

        def parse(self, response):
                f = open("eps.txt", "a+")
                sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
                sites = sel.select("//div")
#               items = []
                for site in sites:
                        symbolList = []
                        epsList = []
                        item = EPSItem()
                        item['symbol'] = site.select("h2/span[contains(@id, 'qteSymb')]/text()").extract()
                        item['eps']  = site.select("table/tbody/tr/td[contains(@class, 'rating')]/span/text()").extract()
                        strSymb = str(item['symbol'])
                        newSymb = strSymb.replace("[]","").replace("[u'","").replace("']","")
                        strEps = str(item['eps'])
                        newEps = strEps.replace("[]","").replace(" ","").replace("[u'\\r\\n","").replace("']","")
                        if newSymb.strip():
                                symbolList.append(newSymb)
#                               print symbolList
                        if newEps.strip():
                                epsList.append(newEps)
#                               print epsList
                        print symbolList, epsList
                for symb, eps in izip(symbolList, epsList):
                        f.write("%s\t%s\n", (symb, eps))
                f.close()
```

Comment: You should be doing `bList.append(b.strip())`

Comment: What does the *documentation* say [`strip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) does?

Comment: Strings are immutable; `.strip()` can not alter the value, so it returns a *new* stripped string object.

Comment: @Matjin See that is what I read so I thought of trying to assign it to another variable, but that didnt change anything.

Answer (score 8):

`strip` does not modify the string in-place. It returns a new string with the whitespace stripped.

```
>>> a = '    foo      '
>>> b = a.strip()
>>> a
'    foo      '
>>> b
'foo'
```

Comment: I believe I tried something similar to that where I did this:
    if a.strip():
        b = a
    if c.strip():
        d = c

But when I tried to print this outside of the if statements it printed with all the whitespace.

Comment: As a side-note Python has several built-in types (numbers, booleans, strings, tuples, frozensets) are immutable.

Comment: @Resin As I said, `a.strip()` returns a new string - `a` is not modified. So when you write `if a.strip(): b = a`, it will set `b` to the original (unstripped) variable `a`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what it was that was causing the confusion. Its the location which I declared the variable/list. I was declaring it inside the for loop so everytime it iterated it rewrote and a blank list or variable is the same outcome of false for my if statement.